# SSH Shell Script

Tags: ssh, sh

I am trying to do a shell script that can connect to a remote machine via ssh

then problem is that I can relly on keys and stuff like that. I just want to add the hostname, user and pass and execute some commands... can someone guide me on that path?

Comment: Why do you suppose a product (and for some, a way of life) that is named **Secure** shell (ssh), would allow you to say, 'Oh, nevermind about the security part' ;-)? You either have to submit a password when you start the program, OR have key files set up on your remote machines OR use expect. Sorry, that's the way it is. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Look into [expect](http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect) for linux.

The script would look something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn ssh root@IPADDRESS /script/on/remote/machine
expect "*?assword:*"
send -- "PASSWORDHERE\r"
```

Comment: I would really like to avoid expect

Comment: I don't want to have to install 3rd party

Answer (score 0):

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096
ssh-copy-id youruser@remote.host
ssh youruser@remote.host 'ls -la ~ ; pwd ; uname -a '
```